# Unexpected template string expression in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

everytime I code like this ${row.name}, I get this error "eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string  Unexpected template string expression".

Any help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Disallow template literal placeholder syntax in regular strings (no-template-curly-in-string)](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string#examples)

Comment: All eslint errors and warnings have complete documentation pages. You should Google for the error, not ask on SO.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

ES6 template strings should be used with backquotes, not single quotes.
Replace this :

```
'delete the item ${row.name}'
```

With this :

```
`delete the item ${row.name}`
```

And here is the ESLint example as requested in the comments : http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string#examples

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using an ES6 template string and actually want the dollar sign to print to the screen, place the following above the string declaration.

```
/* eslint-disable no-template-curly-in-string */
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its necessary to use templating characters within string,
like inside anchor tags, etc.

```
'<a href="${' +
'OrganizationInfo.PrivacyPolicy}" target="_blank" >Privacy Policy</a>'
```

Breaking the string worked for me.